Parse iOS XCode: Class names cannot start with an underscore
I am getting this error at initialization of Parse.
Most likely it is because I updated to XCode Version 16.0 (16A242d). MacOS is 14.5 (23F79).
I have installed Parse as a pod. Also tried to remove it and install latest version as a Package Dependency but same error.
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
            configuration.applicationId = @"myAppId";
            configuration.clientKey = nil;
            configuration.server = @"myParseServerUrlStringHostedonHeroku";
}]];

Here is what I get when I run the app: (No errors while compiling.)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: Invalid class name. Class names cannot start with an underscore.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804ae0f8 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180087db4 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804ae008 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106d2f1f8 +[PFObject(Private) _assertValidInstanceClassName:] + 180
    4   myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106d37598 -[PFObject init] + 436
    5   myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106d37898 -[PFObject initWithObjectState:] + 92
    6   myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106d379cc +[PFObject objectWithClassName:objectId:completeData:] + 248
    7   myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106d37ae0 +[PFObject objectWithClassName:] + 80
    8   myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106d37fcc +[PFObject object] + 252
    9   myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106cf6bdc __56-[PFCurrentInstallationController getCurrentObjectAsync]_block_invoke.9 + 452
    10  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a64f18 __62-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:successBlock:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke + 124
    11  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a64848 __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke + 88
    12  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a615c0 __29+[BFExecutor defaultExecutor]_block_invoke_2 + 152
    13  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a61da0 -[BFExecutor execute:] + 88
    14  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a64b24 __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke.15 + 44
    15  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a642f4 -[BFTask runContinuations] + 508
    16  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a63cd8 -[BFTask trySetResult:] + 208
    17  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a65a50 -[BFTaskCompletionSource trySetResult:] + 88
    18  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106ce88fc __28-[PFAsyncTaskQueue enqueue:]_block_invoke_2 + 216
    19  myApp.debug.dylib   0x0000000106a64848 __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke + 88
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001022cbec4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001022cd73c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001022d05a0 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1320
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001022e136c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001022e1f18 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 256
    25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001022277d8 _pthread_wqthread + 224
    26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001022265d4 start_wqthread + 8

After debugging, this was causing the trouble:
In PFObject:
+ (instancetype)object {
    PFConsistencyAssert([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PFSubclassing)],
                        @"Can only call +object on subclasses conforming to PFSubclassing");
    NSString *className = [(id<PFSubclassing>)self parseClassName];
    Class class = [[self subclassingController] subclassForParseClassName:className] ?: [PFObject class];
    return [class objectWithClassName:className];
}

NSString *className = [(id<PFSubclassing>)self parseClassName]; in this line className comes out to be "_Installation" because in PFInstallation there is:
+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"_Installation";
}

Also, [[self subclassingController] subclassForParseClassName:className] return nil.
Spent almost entire day on this without breaks and frustrated. All I have a doubt on is that the subclasses are not registering in Parse->Core->PFObjectSubclassingController:
- (void)registerSubclass:(Class<PFSubclassing>)kls {
    pf_sync_with_throw(_registeredSubclassesAccessQueue, ^{
        [self _rawRegisterSubclass:kls];
    });
}

which gives a nil at [[self subclassingController] subclassForParseClassName:className].
Please help! Desperately in need. Thank you!

https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1792

You need a specific commit for the swift package. It’s in the issues.

We ran into the same issue. Simple fix is to register your PFObject classes at app start.
On macOS Swift, it can be done here.
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    PFInstallation.registerSubclass()
    PFUser.registerSubclass()
    PFSession.registerSubclass()
    PersonClass.registerSubclass()
}

we found it to be more convenient to do it here:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = Constants.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID
        $0.clientKey = Constants.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY
        $0.server = Constants.PARSE_SERVER
    }

    Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
    
    PFInstallation.registerSubclass()
    PFUser.registerSubclass()
    PFSession.registerSubclass()
    PersonClass.registerSubclass()
}

assuming your classes, like our PersonClass above, conforms to the PFObject, PFSubclassing protocols
